# How to run import profile using SSH in Magento

Tags: magento, ssh, import

I have a large product data (around 10k) to import in Magento CE 1.7.0.2 and it is taking too much time in this process. Is this possible using SSH or any other solution that I can import products in faster way?

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import the simple and configurable product.It is better to use Magmi for import purpose.This is very fast.I have imported 21K product at once using this.